# Running a VB6 exe over the network - does it make a local copy during execution?

Tags: windows, networking, vb6, share, exe

I've inherited an executable written in VB 6 which users run via a network share.

The users simply double click the file on the share, and the 3MB exe runs.

My question is, when accessed this way, does the user's machine (Win XP) make a temp local copy and run that, or is it constantly making requests of the file on the network (eg, when switching to a new screen)?

I've checked the temp locations on my own machine when running it, with no evidence of a local copy, but perhaps it's handled completely in the background (ie, invisible to a user)?

PS - I'm aware of several disadvantages with this approach but it's not going to change.

Comment: No copy is made.  If the network goes down then the program is likely to crash.  You could technically run Editbin.exe with the [/SWAPRUN option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0628bwh.aspx) to turn on an option in the executable header that forces the operating system to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

The language your programm is written in doesn't matter here.

There will be no local copy of the executable nor will it constantly making requests of the file on the network. 
Your Programm will be loaded from the network into the memory.
Not only the variables but the whole command instructions are loaded into the RAM, otherwise applications would run really slow.
If there are additional "local" files the exe needs, like config files, they are requested from the network during the exection.

I don't know how dll's are handeld but it's probably the same.

Furher information:
[Microsoft Win32 Portable Executable File Format Described](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

**in short:** there are no furhter network requests after loading the exe

Comment: A correction, executables (or rather chunks (pages) of the executable) can be paged out or discarded from ram, "knowing" it can reload those chunks from the (potentially) remote file system. This can be observed when you have an application running from a network share that has been disconnected. Features on the same screen may well still work, but any "new" activity will try and access the remote file and crash with a paging error.

Comment: @Deanna: When /SWAPRUN:NET flag is set on the executable it is first copied to the local swap file, then loaded in RAM. The net effect is that no network requests are required at any time to run obscure features of the applications.

Comment: @wqw I know, but that's not the default. It also wasn't mentioned in the answer I gave the correction to.